# Unable to copy multiple files from remote sftp via ssh

Tags: ssh, sftp, mget

I am trying to copy multiple (1000s) .JPG files from remote SFTP server to current server using mget command but it is not working. Here is the command that I used

```
sftp username@sftp.domain.com
sftp> cd /images
sftp> mget *.JPG
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Nothing happens so when I do CTRL + C it gives an error that says `File "/images/*.JPG" not found.`

I have already referred all suggestions posted on the forum but nothing is working. Let me know if there is another way to copy.

Comment: Do you have too many files in that folder? Also please mind case (jpg is no the same as JPG).

Comment: Hi @LatinSuD yes, there are around 30000 files and all the files ends with .JPG not .jpg so it is not case sensitive?

Comment: How long do you let it run until you press ^C ?

Comment: @LatinSuD 30 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, and it may be version/flavor dependent, sftp does not have an mget option as ftp does. Assuming this is a *nix type system, take a look at the man page to verify syntax. It may be that trying get instead of mget will work.

Comment: I did tried get but it goes to blank as shown in the image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/bSciQ.png

Comment: `get` worked but I had to wait 8 hours to copy entire files. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using a plain get, from the man page

> Retrieve the remote-path and store it on the local machine.  If
>            the local path name is not specified, it is given the same name
>            it has on the remote machine.  remote-path may contain glob(3)
>            characters and may match multiple files.  If it does and
>            local-path is specified, then local-path must specify a direc-
>            tory.

Alternatively you could use scp.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
scp -r username@sftp.domain.com:/fullpath/images/*.JPG /your/path/destination
```

Note that the names are case sensitive and verify if you are in the correct path on your `cd` command.